# How to color letters in gtktextview with gtkcssprovider

Tags: python, css, gtk

Hey i was wondering if it's possible to color specific letters in gtktextview with a css style sheet.

for example.

```
.T {
    color: blue;
}
.A {
   color: red;
}
etc..
```

i currently have this,

```
GtkTextView {
    color: blue
}
```

but it makes all the textview blue! 
i dont know if this is possible, or if there's another quick way to do this.
Doing tags takes much processing power with a lot of text. so i'm looking for a faster alternative and css looks promising.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you suggest is not possible. I would suggest using [`GtkSourceView`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView) and creating a special syntax highlighting language for your letters. (This, of course, will use tags under the hood, but then again CSS would take just as much processing power under the hood too.)

I actually don't know if it's possible to style `GtkTextTag`s themselves with CSS; you might want to look into that.