# change background color of GtkTextView (GTK 3.22) using CSS

Tags: css, linux, gtk3

I would like to change (on Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64, GTK 3.22) the *default* background color (for untagged text) in a [GtkTextView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkTextView.html) (or else its GtkTextBuffer).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21485264/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15516032/841108) answers don't help (are obsolete).

In my [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) program (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46809878/841108) question for details) I tried, on some global `extern GtkWidget *commandview_BM;` initialized with:

```
commandview_BM = gtk_text_view_new_with_buffer (commandbuf_BM);
gtk_widget_set_name (commandview_BM, "commandview");
```

To use

```
#commandview {
    background-color: seashell;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Inconsolata;
}
```

in my `bismon.css`  file, but that does not work. Replacing `#commandview` by `#commandview.text` or `#commandview.view` don't change anything.

I would also be happy if some *default* tag existed in [GtkTextBuffer](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkTextBuffer.html)-s,  but this does not seem to be the case.

I have (at least) two textviews in the same window (one for commands; another for logging) and I would like them to have different background colors.

Answer (score 3):

The working syntax in CSS file is with a space to separate the name from the class, so in my case:

```
#commandview text {
    background-color: seashell;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: Inconsolata;
}
```

Comment: check [Gtk Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Inspector). It's a nice tool and permits runtime CSS debugging among other things.